# Discrete Time Convolution

Tags: summation, convolution, signal-processing, discrete-time

I'm trying to solve a problem on convolution from Alan V.Oppenheim:

Find the convolution output $y[n]$ for the following signals:

$x[n]= u[n]$ and $h[n]=a^{n}u[-n-1], a>1 $

I started the evaluation:

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} u[k]a^{n-k}u[-n+k-1]$$
considering that $u[k]=1$ for $k>=0$ and $u[-n+k-1]=1$ for $k>=n+1$
which I evaluated to
$$y[n]=a^{n}\sum_{k=m}^{+\infty} a^k$$ where $m=n+1$ could be $<0$ or $>0$
and I tried to evaluate for $m>0$ which is the same as $n>-1, which evaluated as:

$$y[n]=a^{n}\sum_{k=m}^{+\infty} a^m=a^{n}((\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a^m)-(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} a^m))=a^{n}((\frac{1}{1-a^{-1}})-(\frac{1-a^{-m}}{1-a^{-1}}))=\frac{a^{n-m}}{1-a^{-1}}=\frac{a^{-1}}{1-a^{-1}}$$ since n-m=1,

but when I evaluated for m<0  which is n<=-1 I'am facing a problem:

$$y[n]= a^{n}((\sum_{k=m}^{-1} a^m)+(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a^m))$$

How do I evaluate the first summation. I mean am I to consider k=-m since m<0?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what is $u[n]$ for n negative?